# Why queryselectorAll not working for removing element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
    <ul class="items">
        <li class="item">item1</li>
        <li class="item">item2</li>
        <li class="item">item3</li>
        <li class="item">item4</li>
        <li class="item">item5</li>
    </ul>
```

const ul = document.querySelector('.items'); 
ul.remove(); 
This will remove the complete html.
const li = document.querySelector('.item'); li.remove() will remove the first li element.
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
 lis.remove(); is giving error => Uncaught TypeError: ul.remove is not a function. 
Why it is not working with the querySelectorAll method?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, which does not have a `remove` function. You have to use `forEach` or a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelectorAll returns a list, that you have to iterate through manually:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".item")
for (const element of list) {
  element.remove()
}
```